# Passing a dictionary between two viewcontrollers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an application in which I have a webservice call that returns data as a dictionary. I want to access this dictionary in another view controller for loading the values into a table.

Can anybody demonstrate how to pass this response dictionary from one view controller to another?

Comment: Using functions or NSUserDefaults or take the dictionary allocated and synthesized in appdelegate etc

Comment: you may try using protocols to access data from other viewcontrollers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define an `NSDictionary` property in your `AnotherViewController` and set it from the previous controller. I'll give a brief example below.

```
//.h
@interface AnotherViewController {

  NSDictionary *data;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary *data;
@end

//.m
@implementation AnotherViewController
@synthesize data;
```

Now from the current controller, after initializing `AnotherViewController` you set the dictionary before presenting it.

```
AnotherViewController *controller = [[AnotherViewController alloc] init];
controller.data = myCurrentDictionary;
```

Now `AnotherViewController` has a `data` property with the value of the previous controller.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the webservice is called because something happened (button clicked, `viewDidLoad`/`viewDidAppear`). If this is the case, passing a reference of the `UIViewController` to the webservice class is a perfect valid option. Keep in mind that for this relationship you should create a protocol, so on your webservice class you have something like this:

```
id<ViewControllerResponseProtocol> referenceToViewController;
```

This `ViewControllerResponseProtocol`would define a method like this:

```
-(void)responseFromWebservice:(NSDictionary*)myDictionary;
```

So when the webservice class has build the `NSDictionary` you can the above method from the `referenceToViewController`:

```
[referenceToViewController responseFromWebservice:myDictionary];
```

If there isn't any kind of relationship between both, you use could `NSNotificationCenter` for it.

**P.S**: The solution of skram is perfectly valid if you already have the `NSDictionary` from the webservice on the initial `UIViewController` and now you want to pass it to a new `UIViewController`. Although I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: as stated by the OP, he would like to "..`access` the dictionary in another view controller". Meaning he already has it. Don't think a downvote was called for that :)

Comment: Has it where? If he has it on the `UIViewController`that started the action, he should **accept your answer**.

Comment: `another view controller` means it's already in `a` view controller and he wants the data in `another one`

Comment: Well don't worry then, I am sure your answer will be accepted. You are also assuming that the new view controller doesn't exist (you are creating it).